# Java Applet is not working correctly in html : graph is plotted but without any data

Tags: java

I have coded Java applet to read xml files from a current folder and display the data in a bar graph.I have signed this applet and running it on IE or firefox via html applet tag.

Problem : the bar graph is generating but without any data. So I think the applet is not able to locate the files or read them. Please let me know what can I do to resolve this problem.

[This is the applet output from eclpis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv9WL.png)

[This is the applet output ran via html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGtbs.png)

Below is the code for html

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252"/>

<body>

<applet code=ExtractXmlData.class width="500" height="500" 
archive="jfreechart-1.0.19.jar ,
jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar,
jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar,
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar,
jcommon-1.0.23.jar,
jfreesvg-2.0.jar,
junit-4.11.jar,
orsoncharts-1.4-eval-nofx.jar,
orsonpdf-1.6-eval.jar,
servlet.jar,swtgraphics2d.jars,
export1.jar" >

</applet>

</body>

</html>
```

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset; 
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset; 
import org.w3c.dom.Attr; 
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class ExtractXmlData extends JApplet {

    public static Vector<Float> DeviceData=new Vector<Float> ();
    public static Vector<String>  time=new Vector<String> ();
    public static Vector<String>  deviceName=new Vector<String> ();
    public static Vector<String>  DeviceSIunit=new Vector<String> ();
    public static Vector<String>  numberOfDevice=new Vector<String> ();

    public void start (){


    }


    public void init ()  {
         File file = new File(".");

            File[] files = file.listFiles();

            for(File f: files){


           if (f.getName().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
            {
    try {

      DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File(  f.getName()));

      doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();


      NodeList listOfDevice = doc.getElementsByTagName("device");
      int totalDevice = listOfDevice.getLength();
     // Node nodesdevice = listOfDevice.item(0);

      numberOfDevice.add(Integer.toString(totalDevice));


      NodeList nodesTime = doc.getElementsByTagName("time");        
        Node nodetime = nodesTime.item(0);      
        //String time = nodetime.getTextContent();
        time.add( nodetime.getTextContent());


        for(int s=0; s<listOfDevice.getLength() ; s++){
          Node firstDeviceNode = listOfDevice.item(s);

          //read the name of the sensor from "tag"
          Node prop = listOfDevice.item(s);
          NamedNodeMap attr = prop.getAttributes();
          if (null != attr) {
            final Attr attribute = (Attr) attr.item(1); 
              final String value = attribute.getValue();
              deviceName.add(value);
          }


          if(firstDeviceNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
              Element DeviceElement = (Element)firstDeviceNode;
              //-------
              NodeList DeviceValueList = DeviceElement.getElementsByTagName("v1");
              Element DeviceValueElement = (Element)DeviceValueList.item(0);
              NodeList textDeviceList = DeviceValueElement.getChildNodes();
              DeviceData.add(Float.parseFloat(((Node)textDeviceList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim()));
          //    System.out.println("Device value : " + 
          //           ((Node)textDeviceList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

              NodeList SIunitList = DeviceElement.getElementsByTagName("u1");
              Element SIunitElement = (Element)SIunitList.item(0);
              NodeList textSIunit = SIunitElement.getChildNodes();
              DeviceSIunit.add(((Node)textSIunit.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
          }
      }

  }
    catch (Throwable t) {
  t.printStackTrace ();
  }
      }

     }


    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        chart.draw( (Graphics2D)g,getBounds()); 
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(DefaultCategoryDataset dataset) 
    {    
          JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
             "Sensors output",           
             "Time",            
             "Values",            
             dataset,          
             PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,           
             true, true, false);
          return chart;
       }

     private static DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset() 
       {

          final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = 
          new DefaultCategoryDataset( );  

          int startOfDevice = 0;

          for (int timeindex = 0;timeindex< time.size()-1; timeindex++)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i< numberOfDevice.size()-1; i++)
            {
                dataset.addValue( DeviceData.elementAt(startOfDevice) , deviceName.elementAt(startOfDevice) + " ( "+ DeviceSIunit.elementAt(startOfDevice) + " )" , time.elementAt(timeindex) );  
                startOfDevice = startOfDevice +1;
            }
          }

          return dataset; 
       }

}
```

Comment: `JS` **!=** `Java`

Comment: Hi, 

Yes I understand, its my first post and I dont know how to put the java code in the question as it was giving me error every time.

Comment: Do not develop new Java applets - this is a dieing technology. Java support in Firefox will be dropped end of 2016 and IE has also been replaced by Edge.

Comment: Is it possible to suggest an alternate language which I can opt for the same algorithm that I want to implement.

thank you.

Comment: Yes, [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/). Its the only, real alternative since ut supports AJAX data transmission out of the box - you simply need to re-write a few things (for AJAX instead of direct field access) and that should be about it - you also need to write UI logic code